# No Bibliography is printed and citations shown bibtex key

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdf, lyx, printing

I writing a document in LyX (2.0.5) with references. For displaying references I use `biblatex`.
(http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex). My latex environment is MiKTeX 2.9

Since I switched my Desktop, converting following tex files to pdf doesn't work anymore. Converting the Lyx file (which following tex file is exported from) doesn't work either.

Here is my tex file:

```
%% LyX 2.0.5 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1.2cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{list-4.bib}
\typeout{File: \jobname.bcf}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}    
Test (\citealp[see][p.1]{Alter1980})

\chapter{Literature}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My bib file look like this:

```
@book{Alter1980,
author = {Alter, Steven L.},
 year = {op. 1980},
 title = {{D}ecision support systems: {C}urrent practice and continuing challenges},
 address = {Reading Mass. [etc.]},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley Publ},
 isbn = {0-201-00193-4}
}
```

Hope that I haven't forget any neccessary information.
Hope, someone of you have a hint where the problem may lies ... I have non any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will work. It's like groping in the dark for me since I don't use `LyX`. But I think you have to change your bibliography processor to `biber` by clicking

> Tools > Preferences > Output > LaTeX > Bibliography generation > Processor > Biber

If this does not work, you have to manually run `biber` on your file through your terminal.

`cd` to your working directory and run

`biber myfile` without the file extension. Then try `ctrl-R` again in `LyX` to compile and view your pdf.

Also, with `biblatex`, `\bibliography` is replaced with `\addbibresource`.

Comment: thanx :) the descriped way works for me

Comment: Wow! This worked for me under Windows 10 and LyX 2.2.2. Easiest way to find the working directory is to use Document > LaTeX Log and click the Open Containing Directory button. I used Git Bash to launch the `biber myfile` command there and it fixed the problem. Such an annoying bug! Shouldn't LyX have a way to force this?