# Biber v1.9 with Miktex 2.9 - Bibliography not displayed

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, lyx, miktex

I am trying to compile my Bibliography, but it dosent show up in the output.

I use MikTeX 2.9 & Biber 1.9.

[image: Lyx view]

Further I have this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/alberteschmidt/Dropbox/Speciale materiale/Text/Literatur liste/thesis.bib}
```

Extraxt from the log:

> (C:\Users\alberteschmidt\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.FnfGiKed7740\lyx_tmpbuf0
>   \tjek_text.bbl)
>   Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 19.
>   Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 19.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Type 'book' not found on input line 26.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 26.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Type 'article' not found on input line 27.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 27.
>
> LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 27.
>
> [1
>
> {C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
>   (C:\Users\alberteschmidt\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.FnfGiKed7740\lyx_tmpbuf0
>   \tjek_text.aux)
>   Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'tjek_text.run.xml'.
>    ) 
>   Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>    6954 strings out of 493921
>    118271 string characters out of 3144849
>    534231 words of memory out of 3000000
>    10207 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
>    5953 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
>    841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>    44i,4n,35p,863b,1399s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
>     
>   Output written on tjek_text.pdf (1 page, 6850 bytes).
>   PDF statistics:
>    26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
>    0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>    1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Comment: Does this help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46550/can-i-have-a-path-argument-that-contains-spaces

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Are you sure that the bib-file is actually found and processed? As musicman hints, spaces in paths are nothing but trouble. I'd try moving the bib-file to the directory where your tex-file is and only call it by its name leaving out the path.

Comment: Have you cited any books? Or any articles?

Comment: I have now moved the file to a path without spaces, but it still does not work. I have both articles and books in my bibliography (created with JabRef).. Not sure what to do. But thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Try to find the .blg-file and show its content.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but what is the .blg file and where do I find  it?

Comment: When using `\addbibresource` you must include the the file ending, i.e. `\addbibresource{C:/Users/alberteschmidt/Dropbox/Speciale materiale/Text/Literatur liste.bib}` but please be aware that sometimes spaces in path names cause problems.

Comment: You will also have to set up Lyx to use Biber [here](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86482/35864).

Comment: I have no idea where LyX puts temporary (log) files, it seems somewhere along the lines of `C:\Users\alberteschmidt\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.FnfGiKed7740\lyx_tmpbuf` is your best guess.

Comment: Were you able to locate a `.blg` file? Maybe it is not in the temporary folder, but with your document.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I can't find it.. But thank you for all your suggestions Moewe, greatly appreciated!

Comment: One  more thing: I'm not sure whether this really means something: But in your screen shot it says "BibTeX Generated Bibliography", but of course you have to run Biber. Did you verify that Biber is actually run on your document?

Comment: I believe it is, but I am not sure how to verify that?

Comment: I suppose you have read the links I posted above? If you followed the instructions here you will probably at least have instructed LyX to run Biber. The question of how to verify it actually ran is not that easy to answer as I have no clue where temporary log files are stored with LyX. If you could find a `.blg` file we would know...

Comment: See also here https://nowsimplified.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/where-is-the-lyx-generated-aux-file/ about where to find the temp files. If Biber was actually run I would expect not only `.aux` and `.log` files to be there, but also a `.blg` and a `.bbl`. (I seem to have gathered that the temporary files are removed upon closing LyX, so you will have to let LyX open in the background once you compiled.) The content of your `.blg` file might help us investigate, add it to your question if you can find it.

Comment: When you click `Document > LaTeX Log File` apparently you are directed to the `.log`, theoretically the `.blg` file resides very close to it...