# BibLatex keep producing errors in Lyx 2.1.4 with MikTex

Tags: biblatex, lyx, miktex

As many people suggest to use BibLatex instead of BibTex, but I cannot get it working in Lyx 2.1.4 with MikTex. I have seen many webpages, but still confused.

I followed the instruction in lyx wiki (http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex), but lyx got five errors and cannot output correct PDF file.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[english,ngerman,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is a test of biblatex. \cite{aksin,almendro,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\end{document}
```

And it is strange that if I delete the

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
```

in TeXworks, it works fine.

I really do not know what the problem is in Lyx.

Comment: You will really have to delete the two lines `\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}` to use `biblatex` regardless your editor. AFAIK there is no "native" `biblatex` support in LyX (there wasn't a while ago, at least), have a look at http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144959/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184022/35864, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86482/35864

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as the manual says, is that you haven't put the bibtex button in a comment. This is to trick LyX into using its citation infrastructure without exporting `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` to LaTeX. Note that these two are bibtex commands, they can't be used with biblatex. Check if the examples from http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex work for you.

Comment: I think you are right. Putting the bibtex button which shows like "BibTex Generated Bibliography" in a comment corrects my problem. Thank you!!