# How to use biblatex bibliography database in latest Classicthesis LyX version 4.2

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis-LyX-v4.2_biblatex_bibtex8 issued in Sep 2015. I already have a bib. file by converting endnote to bib. (endnote staff confirmed with me that the file is well-converted). However, I got very confused about how to use database for referencing.

What I want is the very common in-text author-year citation style: ".....(Surname, 2016).....Surname (2015) argues that...."

In the Bibliography section: I want common hanging indent without [number] in front (this is an example from the APA website):
[image]

I have attached the explanation from the template. I followed it and I ended up getting error message when opening the parent Classicthesis lyx file. I also only see about 10% of my references showing up in the box when I click insert->citation. It would be much appreciated if I can get more detailed step-by-step guide from the default setting, for example, telling me what to load first, click what, insert what at which place etc.

[image]

### [UPDATE!]

Since my thesis deadline is one week later, if there is no hope to figure it out , I just want to copy the completed reference pages in word to LyX. It would be nice if any one can teach me how to do the "hanging indent" in LyX, that is, mimicking the final layout I want under "standard" environment.

Please see [my question about hanging indent in Classic thesis LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300783/how-to-creat-hanging-indent-reference-list-in-classicthesis-lyx-version) for details.

Comment: I trust you have read the hints and explanations in the template and the screen shot you provided. Please have a look at the LyX wiki https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex. On this site we have a step-by-step solution in [BibLaTex, Biber and Lyx: how to resolve \bibliographystyle error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299312/35864) as well as [Single LyX file with multiple bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298382/35864). To diagnose your problem in more detail it would be great if you could provide us with both the LaTeX and BibTeX log files.

Comment: I have read it, but I think it is a more customized problem associated with LyX version of Classicthesis template, not with LyX in general. But I am not sure about this either.

Comment: I don't think so, but OK. Have you made sure your LyX is set up exactly as explained in the link? I suspect if you use `classicthesis-LyX-v4.2_biblatex_bibtex8` you will have to set up your LyX to run BibTeX8 and not Biber. (In this day and age using Biber is often the better option, though.)

Comment: Even the original template doesn't seem to compile well for you, let's first investigate that: run both of these http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/Bibliography-BibLaTeX.zip and tell us what Document>LaTeX log>Log Type BibTeX says, is there anything marked as ERROR?

Comment: Maybe something got wrong when I was trying things, now I have copy and pasted my chapter contents into the original template, to start freshly. The parent file opens normally and everything is fine again. Except that I am afraid of doing any self-trying again for the database.

Comment: When I copy the third step in wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex '\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}' into the template, it says it clashes. So I guess I really need a customised solution.

Comment: A common issue with bib files is that they sometimes contain 'weird' characters, or are saved in utf8 encoding while only ascii is supported. I'd start with a subset of your bib file entries, make sure the file name is short, there are no spaces in the whole path... You could also use the old version, 4.1 bugfix, it only differs in the bibliography processor employed. The call to biblatex clashes because that's the second time you're calling it. The command is already in classicthesis-config.tex.

Comment: It would be nice if you could teach me again in this post: how to do the "hanging indent" in LyX, that is, mimicking the final layout I want under "standard" environment. I really this as a backup plan for my submission deadline.

Comment: Your last comment makes me feel even more scary to try: ) I would probably postpone it to after I submit my thesis. I do need to ultimately figure this out as I will write more papers in my future career.

Comment: I guess you could use the Labeling environment for that hanging indent.

Comment: Thank you again. Since it is not quited related to the title of this question, I created a new question [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300783/how-to-creat-hanging-indent-reference-list-in-classicthesis-lyx-version) , which has  screenshots showing the following issues when I followed your suggestion (i) The first letter of the label is not a capital letter; (ii) The space between label letters are slightly wider than that of the subsequent content. (iii) I also want to know how to customize indentation lengths or label lengths.