# How to cross-reference an ERT in LyX?

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, classicthesis, code

I am using Classicthesis LyX version 4.2 template, but I think this question is more general to LyX.

This question is related to my own answer to my previous question [How to creat hanging indent reference list in Classicthesis LyX version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300783/how-to-creat-hanging-indent-reference-list-in-classicthesis-lyx-version)

I want to hyper-reference, for example, "Surname, 2005" in the main text (say, in a child document called Chapter 2) has be clickable and directs to an ERT which is located in another child document-Bibliography.lyx, such as

```
    \begin{hangparas}{1.27cm}{1}
    Surname, A. 2005. This is a bibliography. This is
    a bibliography. This is a bibliography. This is a bibliography. This
    is a bibliography. This is a bibliography.  
    \end{hangparas}
```

Essentially, I want to know how to create and where to put a label for this citation in Bibliography.lyx; then how to cross-reference it in another child document.

28th Oct, 2016: there is still no answer to this question, so any additional comments are welcome.

Comment: With that reference, just cite it writing  "Surname, 2005". Do you know  some BibTeX or biblatex ?

Comment: I want hyper-reference, that it, "Surname, 2005" in the main text (say, in a child document called Chapter 2) has be clickable and directs to this ERT which is located in another child document-Bibliography.lyx. Apologies for not stating my question clearly.

Comment: Then you sould use `thebibliography` environment or a BibTeX bibliography. Both options can be done in LyX via menus without ERT boxes.  Please see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) to a brief introduction of the basics in LaTeX, so you can understand these  LyX options. Moreover, be sure to check "Use Hyperref support" in PDF properties for hyper-references.

Comment: BTW, the use of biblatex is a bit tricky in LyX.  For now just learn how to use BibTeX in LyX.

Comment: Thx a lot. I am aware of the standard way, but it takes time to download hundreds of existing citations in BibTex format, and using biblatex in Classicthesis LyX may be even more stricky. Since I already have them in Microsoft Word format, I am interested in the shortcut or workaround. I will go throught the introduction you provided for future citations.

Comment: There is still no answer to this question, so any additional comments are welcome.

Comment: Sincerely I haven't understood your problem (you aren't using any bibliographical tool and you want to have hyperlinks anyway, is it?), but using BibLaTeX in LyX is not too difficult, see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314926/citations-in-footnotes-on-the-same-page-using-lyx/314996#314996).

Comment: Yes, you may wish to refer to my own anwer for the previous question to see how I came to this step.  I am aware of the standard way using BibLaTeX, but I am more interested in solving the current problem.

Comment: Off-topic but just to help you: when you post a comment put @ plus the nickname of the person you want to reach, otherwise the person is not notified, unless he/she is the author of the question/answer you commented. I wasn't notified of your reply, sorry!

Comment: @CarLaTeX , thank you. Please let me know if you have not been notified by this comment.

Comment: This is perfect! Ciao!

Comment: @Fran, I just figured it out by myself, just in case you wish to have a look. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by myself again.

In the reference list, just utilize`\hypertarget`and type in the ERT as follows:

```
\begin{hangparas}{1.27cm}{1}
\hypertarget{Surname}{Surname, A. 2005.} This is a bibliography. This is
a bibliography. This is a bibliography. This is a bibliography. This
is a bibliography. This is a bibliography.  
\end{hangparas}
```

That is, create a label name called Surname or anything, and use curly brackets to surround the "Surname, A. 2005." part.

In the main text, type
`\hyperlink{Surname}{Surname, 2005}` shows that...

Note: need to use Ctrl+L to creat  ERT whenever you want to insert the latex codes.

Outcome:

[image]

Once click the blue words, it leads to the specific location of the citation in the reference list.

Comment: Hopefully this solution together with the one in my previous question can help those who want to transform reference lists in Word version to LyX version. Although it took me a while to figure this out as a learner, it should only take minutes for you to do this.