# Adding a bibliography in LyX with \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx

I have the following problem to add a bibliography in LyX with `\printbibliography`:

I created a bib-file in Citavi using the biblatex-filter following the instructions from the Citavi-support. Then I configured LyX to support biber/biblatex as described in the LyX-wiki.

Citavi, LyX, MiKTeK, biber and biblatex are all updated.

When I want to add a bibliography in LyX with `\printbibliography` it does not show up after compiling. I get no error-message.

When I add a reference in the document with the bibtex-key in the LyX-menu the PDF shows just the bibtex-key for instance "Bender.2006" instead of "See Bender, 2006, p. 444".

My LaTeX preamble says:

```
\usepackage[
    style=fiwi,
    bibstyle=fiwi,
    citestyle=fiwi,
    dashed=true,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber,
    urldate=iso8601,
    date=iso8601,
]{biblatex}  
    \addbibresource{C:/Users/User/Documents/Thesis/Thesis - Filmphilosophy/biblatex.bib}
```

Of course I checked the web for users with similar problems.

1. ["Lyx/Biblatex/Biber does not print bibliography"](http://Lyx/Biblatex/Biber%20does%20not%20print%20bibliography). Still no solution. Without success.
2. ["biblatex | A Variety of Problems"](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=11317). Without success.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know if it could be the cause, but spaces in paths can sometimes cause problems, so you could try renaming the `Thesis - Filmphilosophy` folder to remove the spaces.

Comment: Thank you, but it's the same result.

Comment: Can you make a minimal example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/lyx-user-questions-on-tex-stackexchange and http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) and add that to your question?

Comment: Please check out the step-by-step question and answer in [BibLaTex, Biber and Lyx: how to resolve \bibliographystyle error?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299312/35864) as well as [Single LyX file with multiple bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298382/35864), please make sure to read the linked resources thoroughly. Make sure to check out the `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question post, rather post an answer below. (It is perfectly OK to answer ones own question.) That makes it much easier for anyone else to see that you found a solution.

Comment: Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your inputs!

I solved the problem as follows. I am sure this could help other users as well.

As I told you there was no error-message when I was compiling the LyX-file, but when I tried to make a MWE I got the error-message `Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. \sortlist{`.

Following your site this could indicate that there is a mismatch between `biber` and `biblatex`.

But it was impossible for me to update both packages. The update manager told me to restart, whenever I checked (or unchecked) a box. With some help of this forum these are the necessary steps:

```
Synchronize the repository as admin in the package manager.
Synchronize the repository as user in the package manager.
Start the update manager as user, select the packages and run the update.
Start the update manager as admin. Now some boxes are checked, cannot be unchecked and it is not possible to "select all". Run the update anyway.
Start the update manager as admin again. Now it is possible to "select all" and to update the packages.
```

After this it is possible to add references (with the references-menu) and to add a bibliography (with `\printbibliography`).

You can also take the opportunity to rename the bibliography with: `\printbibliography[title=name]`

You can add the bibliography to your TOC if not numbered with: `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`

Enter these both lines after the bibtex-bibliography-comment.

IMPORTANT: If references are added later and they do not show up after compiling, click on the "bibtex-bibliography"-field in the LyX-comment (as described in the how-to-use LyX with biber/biblatex) and choose "read again", otherwise your references will not be added.